# Smooth scrolling and syntax highlighting in MacVim

Tags: vim, textmate, velocity, macvim

Is there any way to get MacVim to scroll more smoothly TextMate style?

While I'm here, is there a syntax file I can edit to add syntax highlighting to files? I have Velocity .vhtml files which are largely regular HTML with a bit of VTL thrown in. If I could just add .vhtml as an extension to the HTML syntax highlighter that would already make things 10x better.

Comment: smoother scrolling with the mouse, or with keyboard navigation?

Comment: Pretty sure the scrolling thing is impossible since the UI scrolls are just sending scroll commands to the underlying Vim engine, and those operate one at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latter question is pretty easy.  Just put this line in `~/.vim/ftdetect/vhtml.vim` (or you can append it to your `~/.vimrc`):

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.vhtml set filetype=html
```

Answer (score 1):

There are now several smooth scrolling plugins for Vim / Neovim, such as https://github.com/yonchu/accelerated-smooth-scroll